# Get text that occurs after a number in a string

Tags: php, regex, substring, text-extraction

I have:

```
$string = "Some minimal or large text 820 some minimal or large descr";
```

I need:

```
some minimal or large descr
```

Answer (score 1):

What about [str_pos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)?

```
<?php
  $string = "Some minimal or large text 820 some minimal or large descr";
  echo substr($string, strpos($string, '820') + 4);
```

Comment: 820 -  for example. String always start from one or more words, numbers can be 1-100000 and one or more words after numbers.  I need to get only words after numbers

Comment: if so, you can use preg_match, or you can split string to words array, then find the first number.

Comment: I don't understand how to use preg_match for my situation. Can you give me example that I need?

Answer (score 1):

The function preg_split can do for you!

It splits the string into an array transforming it ..

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

```
$array = preg_split("/[0-9]+/", "Some minimal or large text 820 some minimal or large descr");
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

To isolate `some minimal or large descr` which comes after the space that follows  `820`, match all non-digital characters from the start of the string until one or more digits, then zero or more spaces.  Replace these matched characters with an empty string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/1HIB1))

```
$string = "Some minimal or large text 820 some minimal or large descr";

var_export(
    preg_replace('/\D*\d+ */', '', $string)
);
```

If multiple numbers may occur and you want the substring after the last occurring number, then greedily match any character before matching a number. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/07ldF))

```
var_export(
    preg_replace('/.*\d+ */', '', $string)
);
```